# Stack Exchange OpenID problem with XRDS

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I'm having trouble using Stack Exchange to sign in using OpenID. I think this is a problem with the [XRDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XRDS) document served at: https://openid.stackexchange.com/xrds

```
openid.claimed_id = https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/9a70fe33-b6aa-44f4-8398-5fb2933ca053
```

OpenID 2 discovery on the above identifier yields a XRDS having
`Service/Type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server` which defines a [OP Identifier Element](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#rfc.section.7.3.2.1.1) (which cannot be claimed by users and therefore proper verification MUST [fail](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#verify_disco)). Discovery on claimed identifiers must yield a [Claimed Identifier Element](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#rfc.section.7.3.2.1.2) in the discovery data (having a Service/Type of http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon).

From https://openid.stackexchange.com/xrds

```
<xrds:XRDS>
    <XRD>
        <Service priority="10">
            <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server</Type>
            <Type>http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1</Type>
            <Type>http://axschema.org/contact/email</Type>
            <URI>https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider</URI>
        </Service>
    </XRD>
</xrds:XRDS>
```

Comment: I'm too new on this forum to vote up, but I'm facing the same issue.  The OpenID 2.0 standard says one should first try Yadis discovery. This results in an OP identifier, so I add a claimed_id and identifier http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select, which then results in an error.